# Asp Net Mvc Identity Multitenancy FindByEmailAsync not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implements a multitenancy application following step by step the Scott Brady post here:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET-Identity/Quick-and-Easy-ASPNET-Identity-Multitenancy

I'm not really sure where I should put these code lines:

```
var context = new ApplicationUserDbContext<ApplicationUser>("DefaultConnection");
var userStore = new ApplicationUserStore<ApplicationUser>(context) { TenantId = 1 };
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>(userStore);
```

I have tried to use this into my login action in AccountController:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var userStore = new ApplicationUserStore<ApplicationUser>(context) { TenantId = tenantId };
UserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(userStore);
SignInManager.UserManager = UserManager;
ApplicationUser userApp =await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
```

But `UserManager.FindByEmailAsync` always returns `null`, any idea of what I should do to get this working? My real objetive is to SingIn User but always return Failure. And I think the problem is finding the `ApplicationUser`.

If you need additional information please, let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you have the user with that email that you are providing?

Answer (score 0):

Your are Using the Classes directly. Give a try with this way...and make sure that you have the user with that gmail that you are providing.

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
var manager =  new ApplicationUserManager(store);
ApplicationUser userApp=await manager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
```